# how many commit logs per cluster?

Tags: cassandra, commit

I am reading thru the Cassandra book, which says there is one commit log per server. What I can't figure out is whether it implies one commit log per cluster. if only one commit log sitting on one server, I can't imagine that is considered a reliable means of guaranteeing a write does not get lost. All that has to happen is that server crashing, any unreplicated data would be lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I got it now. This is a matter of write consistency setting. If the write consistency is set to a quorum of 3, then the initial node will propagate the write request to two other replica nodes and their commit logs would be written to before a success response is returned to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Each server (also called a node) has a commitLog file. If your cluster has multiple nodes (it should for production), each node has a commitLog file.

Comment: i think my question was not clear. so when a write request gets "committed". is it written only on the server that received the request, or is the write request written to multiple commit logs on multiple servers?